# Working with Redis and Entity Framework Core. Error: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, api, redis, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use Redis for my API. And here is the problem.

I'm trying this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Writer>>> GetAllWriters([FromServices] IWriterRepository repository, [FromServices] IDistributedCache cache)
{            
    string recordKey = "Writers_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmm");

    var writers = await cache.GetRecordAsync<IEnumerable<Writer>>(recordKey);

    if (writers == null)
    {
        writers = repository.GetAll();
        await cache.SetRecordAsync(recordKey, writers, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));                
    }
            
    return Ok(writers);
}
```

but I'm getting the error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

I'm a little confused by this error because the EF call can fetch my data, I can save this data to redis and I "can" get the data back from it as well, just need to figure it out the SOLID problem with private set hehe.

I'm open for suggestions :D.

Here is the redis implementation

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed;

namespace Worthix.Api.Extensions
{
    public static class DistributedCacheExtensions
    {
        public static async Task SetRecordAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache,
            string recordId, T data, TimeSpan? absoluteExpireTime = null, TimeSpan? unusedExpireTime = null)
        {
            var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions();

            options.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = absoluteExpireTime ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            options.SlidingExpiration = unusedExpireTime;

            var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            await cache.SetStringAsync(recordId, jsonData, options);
        }

        public static async Task<T> GetRecordAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string recordId)
        {            
            var jsonData = await cache.GetStringAsync(recordId);

            if (jsonData == null)
                return default(T);

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonData);
        }
    }
}
```

and his startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

    // services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("database"));
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionString")));

    services.AddScoped<IWriterRepository, WriterRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IBookRepository, BookRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<WriterHandler, WriterHandler>();
    services.AddTransient<BookHandler, BookHandler>();            

    services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(opt =>
            {
                opt.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionStringRedis");
                opt.InstanceName = "Worthix_";
            });
}
```

I hope there is enough info.

Comment: we can forget about redis here - this is entirely ADO.NET, so: EF; are you perhaps sharing that repository instance between multiple concurrent requests? where did the connection come from? the error message is quite clear: there are two open queries on the connection, when there should only be one. Also: what line is throwing the exception? (nit: images are the absolute worst way to share code)

Comment: You are passing the variables services to ConfigurationServices.  services is being passed by reference so after you call ConfigurationServices the new items is in the list so it is not private.

Comment: @MarcGravell Sorry, its my first post. I will edit the question, appreciate the tip
It is a simple Demo using DDD, CQRS and EF, so no concurrent requests, if i discard the redis call, i can retrieve the data from EF.
The exception happens on the end of the endpoint at  `return Ok(writer)`

Comment: @jdweng you mean the startup class? I did not understand what you mean with the private thing.

Comment: You used the word private.  Trying to figure out what is private.  the only thing I see as private is the collection you send to  ConfigurationServices

Comment: @jdweng aaah, you mean the SOLID thing. When the redis return my data, it tries to map with my entity and the entity has every property as private set, because of SOLID. i'm probably going to make a model on the api with all my domain entity props

Comment: Deserialization doesn't work with private properties.  Usually the Entity object context is an instance of the class data class.  And a Controller isn't usually 
entity.  So you want you Entity Model and the Controller results use the same Model?

Comment: @jdweng i know it doesnt. I just dont know how to make it with a good design, since I'm using DDD and CQRS, it is a test so I'm trying to make everything clear. And the private set won't be a problem if redis doesnt work anyway haha

Comment: You need to have an instance of both the Entity Model and Controller model.  and then create a method to move data between the two instances.  You could create Interface to access the private properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update.

I figure it out. I still don't know why this error was happening.

I refactored EF Core queries to async and it worked, if anyone have any ideia why this errors happened, I will mark as the correct answer.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Writer>>> GetAllWriters([FromServices] IWriterRepository repository, [FromServices] IDistributedCache cache)
{

    string recordKey = "Writers_All_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmm");

    var writersModel = await cache.GetRecordAsync<IEnumerable<WriterModel>>(recordKey);

    if (writersModel == null)
    {
        var writers = await repository.GetAll();
        await cache.SetRecordAsync(recordKey, writers);
        return Ok(writers);
    }

    return Ok(writersModel);
}
```